# what is wrong with my approach to trisection?

Tags: geometry

I cannot find what is wrong with my approach to trisecting an angle. I used it to find solutions for many arbitrary angles including 60 degrees. The steps seems right but?
Please help me locate where in the steps I violate the rules.The complete approach is below.
https://www.slideshare.net/HAROLDFLORENTINOLATO/graphic-trisection-of-an-arbitrary-angle 
The comparison between the graphic and the algebraic solution is presented in the second table of the slideshare.

Comment: Your demonstration is a bit complicated. Some of the lines (or curves) can be skipped because it will be sufficient if you can show that the left part of your construction can yield an angle that is one-third of the original.

Comment: One more thing, if the original angle is larger than 45 degrees, then point G will be outside of the original angle. Does it matter?

Comment: It does not matter. In fact the last table shows the graphic results from several angles from 0 to 180 degrees.

Comment: Let me take the opportunity to point out that the original angle is considered only in the second figure to define BC and the last figure to find the trisection. In fact, the whole graph is a template. Once the apex A is on the bissector line and the sides pass through B and C, the solutions are at the intersects of the arc circle with the loci.

Comment: What are "Locus 1" and "Locus 2"?

Comment: Locus 1 and locus 2 are defined in figures 22 and 23. They are the loci of the solutions for all angles. Thank you once more for your interest. I am willing to send you the complete analysis via email, if I can find an address.

Comment: Blue, I used the site trigonographer on your profile to send you a copy of the complete analysis. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @FlatortueMethod: I don't see where the Loci are *defined* in your slides; I only see arrows pointing at ... *something*. I can *guess* that they are defined as the (other) points of intersection of the recently-constructed arcs, but this kind of detail really needs to be stated explicitly. Also, it's not clear what the parameters of the locus are. Angle $\alpha$, surely, but all we're told beyond that is that $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles. Is the triangle's *base* held constant as $\alpha$ varies? or maybe the *arms*? the *altitude*? [continued]

Comment: Even if your loci comprise trisecting-pts, that doesn't necessarily count as a ruler-and-compass construction of such pts. The only *continuous* objects assumable are circles and lines. All other pts are constructed discretely, so arguing that your final circle intersects the loci is invalid. Now, the locus-pts constructed for your $\alpha$ are not the trisection-pts for that $\alpha$ (not that you say they are); rather, $\alpha$'s trisection-pts are the locus-pts constructed from some other angle, say, $\beta$; for a complete proof, you must show that $\beta$ is constructible from $\alpha$.

Comment: @blue: I sent you a copy, via email to your site 'trigonometer', of the detailed analysis that gives all the explanations you mentioned. I am willing to provide it again to you. Just send me a request at Flatortuemethod@gmail.com Again thanks for your help

Comment: @FlatortueMethod: I have the email, thanks. But your question refers to the construction as detailed in the slide presentation. Unless you plan to send your document to each potential answerer on this site, it's important that the slide version be as clear as possible on the details.

Comment: @FlatortueMethod: BTW, your doc indicates that the Loci are the arms of some hyperbola (which seems plausible enough). If you do a web search for "trisect an angle using a hyperbola", you'll find that such an approach was known in classical times. However, this still doesn't count as a ruler-&-compass construction. Consider ... [continued]

Comment: If I have point $P$ and line $\ell$, then I can construct (with ruler & compass) points that are equidistant from them; these points, I know, happen to lie on a parabola with focus $P$ and directrix $\ell$. While I can construct as many points as I like, "the parabola" ---as a continuous geometric object--- is not available to me to use for other steps in a construction. The parabola may intersect *this* circle, or *that* line, or *some other* parabola, or *whatever*, but the intersection points are only valid to a classical construction if I can get at them with lines and circles alone.

Comment: (I keep writing "ruler". Of course, I *mean* "straightedge".)

Answer (score 2):

Your warning 1 is clearly incorrect when you write
"WARNING 1: Nobody can prove that a problem is impossible to resolve. One can only demonstrate that they cannot provide a solution. Florentino Latortue"

It HAS been proved that
trisection of a general angle
is impossible using only
straightedge and compass.

Therefore,
your attempted construction
has to be incorrect.

Where is the analysis of
your construction method?

Comment: i wrote a whole book about it with the algebraic analysis. What I need is someone to find the flaw in the graphic method since i cannot find it myself. https://www.amazon.fr/Graphic-Trisection-arbitrary-angle-impossible/dp/0692870121/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1492479775&sr=8-2&keywords=trisectrice

Comment: It is foolish to expect anyone to pay 30€ to read a proof that is known a priori to be wrong. The least you should do is provide a link to a free PDF.

Comment: I am taking the liberty to send you the requested file via the email you have on your profile. Once again thank you for your interest.